# Codeigniter Blue Hue

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, gdlib

**UPDATE: THE ANSWER IS USE THE GD2 LIBRARY, DOH!**

I am working with Codeigniter's image manipulation library to resize some photos. Unfortunately, they are producing a blue tint or hue to the photos. Not sure why this is and needed to see if it was something I am doing. Here is the code I am using to create the thumb's. Let me know if you want to see image links, and I will upload them somewhere.

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$config['image_library'] = 'GD';
$config['source_image'] ="images/IMG_0007.jpg";
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width'] = '450';
$config['height'] = '450';

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);

if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
{
   echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

Comment: Have you tired any other image libraries? $config['image_library']

Comment: @michael not yet, what other ones are supported by CI?

Comment: @michael just tried the GD2 library and it doesn't have any issues with colors...hmmm oh well!

Comment: Cool. It's probably just a color profiling issue with that library.

Comment: Nathan, post your 'answer' as an ANSWER below, and just checkbox it as the answer.  This is proper format for SO.  Enjoy!

Comment: @Jakub I cannot submit an answer for 8 hours because of my newbness on SO, sorry. As soon as I can I will update with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to use ImageMagick for image resizing. It respects color profiles, is slightly faster, less memory hungry and generally produces better quality. See this question:

[How to stop GD2 from washing away the colors upon resizing images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773032/how-to-stop-gd2-from-washing-away-the-colors-upon-resizing-images)

If you do not have ImageMagick installed, this may be of help:

http://ferdychristant.com/blog//archive/DOMM-8GAFGL