# Photo has wrong colors after resized with PHP script

Tags: php, image, jpeg

I'm using the following PHP function to resize big images to fit 500 px width:

```
<?php
function resizeImage($name) {
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$filename = "file.jpg";
$new_width = 500;
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_height = (($height*$new_width)/$width);
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($image_p, "file.jpg", 100);
}
?>
```

For some reason the colors on the resized image aren't exactly the same as before. They aren't as clear and strong as before. As you can see [picture removed] there's more red color and brilliance in the left (original) photo.

Why that? Is there something wrong with my script? Or is it a normal resizing effect?

Comment: Is the original picture RGB or CMYK?

Comment: @MarioWerner It was taken with iPhone. Both, original and resized, are RGB.

Comment: Although both images are RGB, they could have different color spaces like sRGB or AdobeRGB. I don't know if the PHP functions you use can handle color spaces/color profiles or transformations correctly - I suggest this as a starting point for further research.

Comment: Looks like this question has been answered on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773032/how-to-stop-gd2-from-washing-away-the-colors-upon-resizing-images

Comment: @Benni Thanks, but this seems to work for `imagemagick` only. But I don't use it. Any idea what to do?

Comment: @Benni Why does `Imagick` work on my server even I didn't install any library or class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working code I have now:

```
<?php
// Call the function with: resizeImage("INSERT_YOUR_FILE_NAME_INCLUDING_SUFFIX_HERE");
function resizeImage($file_name) {

// File is located at: files/original/
$filename = "files/original/".$file_name;

// The width you want the converted image has
$new_width = 500;

// Calculate right height
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_height = (($height*$new_width)/$width);

// Get image
$small = new Imagick($filename);

// Resize image, but only if original image is wider what the wanted 500 px
if($width > $new_width) {$small->resizeImage($new_width, $new_height, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);}

// Some code to correct the color profile
$version = $small->getVersion();
$profile = "sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_no_black_scaling.icc";
if((is_array($version) === true) && (array_key_exists("versionString", $version) === true)) {$version = preg_replace("~ImageMagick ([^-]*).*~", "$1", $version["versionString"]);if(is_file(sprintf("/usr/share/ImageMagick-%s/config/sRGB.icm", $version)) === true) {$profile = sprintf("/usr/share/ImageMagick-%s/config/sRGB.icm", $version);}}if(($srgb = file_get_contents($profile)) !== false){$small->profileImage("icc", $srgb);$small->setImageColorSpace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);}

// Safe the image to: files/small/
$small->writeImage("files/small/".$file_name);

// Clear all resources associated to the Imagick object
$small->clear();
}
?>
```

Don't forget to either download the icc file from http://www.color.org/sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_no_black_scaling.icc and save it in the same directory as your resize file or change `$profile = "sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_no_black_scaling.icc";` to `$profile = "http://www.color.org/sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_no_black_scaling.icc";`!